# Stream and Feed publish open an empty popup window using Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

For the past few days, without me changing anything (code worked perfectly) i noticed that the stream.publish popup windows i have in my website opened up [with blank content][1]. As if the 'message' parameter that i used on the FB.ui() function is ignored.

The popup window opens ok but it is empty.

Any clues? Has something broken on my part?

You can see the issue live on my website boothchat[.]com if you click on the top right corner the FB icon.

Comment: Include some code... What you have try

Comment: After some kind man pointed this out to me, the 'message' property has been deprecated as of Jul 12th 2011 to meet the new Facebook Platform Policies :/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

So i guess no more pre-set text for feed / stream publish dialogs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can no longer pre-fill a message in the dialog: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/510/

Comment: thank you Abby, i guess i have to turn everything into like buttons... And a new design :/